# Foundation forms - validation errors "End div tag seen, but open elements"

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to style a form using the foundation framework and it doesn't like having sections of the form (namely the submit button) being split with a completely new ROW. It throws these errors;

End tag div seen, but there were open elements. 323
Unclosed element form.  296
Stray end tag form. 329

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CA669/825/)

Here is my code;

```
<!-- Contact -->
<div class="row"> <!-- dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->
<div class="large-12 small-centered columns"> <!-- dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->
<div class="small-12 small-centered large-9 columns"> <!-- dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->

<form method="post" action="#" id="contact_form">
<div class="row">
<div class="large-6 columns">
<label for="contact_name">Your Name<em>*</em></label>
<input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" class="required" />
</div>
<div class="large-6 columns">
<label for="contact_email">Your Email<em>*</em></label>
<input type="email"  id="contact_email" name="contact_email" class="required email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-6 columns">
<label for="contact_company">Company Name or Organization</label>
<input type="text" id="contact_company" name="contact_company"/>
</div>
<div class="large-6 columns">
<label for="contact_phone">Phone Number</label>
<input type="tel" id="contact_phone" name="contact_phone"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<label for="contact_message">Your Message<em>*</em></label>
<textarea id="contact_message" name="contact_message" class="required"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- line 323 - dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->
</div> <!-- dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->
</div> <!-- dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->

<div class="row"> <!-- dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->
<div class="large-4 small-centered columns"> <!-- dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->
<input type="submit" name="contact_submit" class="medium button expand-fix no-border" value="SEND MESSAGE"/></form>
</div> <!-- dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->
</div> <!-- dreamweaver says these overlap or unclosed-->
```

If I nest the last row under line 323 it works but the button does not fill out the column as needed (as its not full width due to being a row > row).

This has me confused! Thanks for looking !

Comment: please see this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CA669/826/

Comment: Does putting the submit button outside of the <form> make it work still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your input elements is unclosed:

```
<input type="email"  id="contact_email" name="contact_email" class="required email">
```

should be:

```
<input type="email"  id="contact_email" name="contact_email" class="required email"/>
```

Also, and more critically, your form tag begins within a div (small-12 small-centered large-9 columns), but that div closes before the form tag does. I'm not sure what your ideal layout is meant to be so I can't show you the exact fix, but there are too many closing div tags in the area near the bottom, where you've got all the comments. Some of those shouldn't close until after the form element.

Go through your code, and make sure that your elements are properly enclosed, and that you do not close off an element before closing off one of it's children first.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realize you couldn't have divs closing before the form does. Cleanup time.

Comment: HTML follows a first in, last out rule.. That is to say, an open element must close before any of it's parent elements can. Some elements, such as input and img are self closing, which means they require the closing slash to be at the end of their tag. It's always best to try to limit nested elements as much as possible, as this will make it easier to keep track of what needs to close when, and will help you avoid accidental overlaps. Good luck!